# Permission denied when running command in terminal by Java Web Start Application

Tags: java, java-web-start

I'm trying to open SANE port by Java Web Start Application, when I run this command by local Java Application it works fine, but it doesn't work when I run it from Web Start Application!

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object>() {
            public Object run() {
                try {                       
                        //Open SANE port
                        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {"bash", "-c", "saned -d128"});
                        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
                        Process saneProcess = processBuilder.start();

                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(saneProcess.getInputStream()));
                        String inputLine;
                        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(inputLine + "\n");
                        }
                        in.close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
```

And here is the output that I get:

> [saned] main: starting debug mode (level 128)
>
> [saned] read_config: searching for config file
>
> [saned] read_config: done reading config
>
> [saned] saned (AF-indep+IPv6) from sane-backends 1.0.24 starting up
>
> [saned] do_bindings: trying to get port for service "sane-port"
>   (getaddrinfo)
>
> [saned] do_bindings: [1] socket () using IPv6
>
> [saned] do_bindings: [1] setsockopt ()
>
> [saned] do_bindings: [1] bind () to port 6566
>
> [saned] do_bindings: [1] bind failed: Permission denied
>
> [saned] do_bindings: [0] socket () using IPv4
>
> [saned] do_bindings: [0] setsockopt ()
>
> [saned] do_bindings: [0] bind () to port 6566
>
> [saned] do_bindings: [0] bind failed: Permission denied
>
> [saned] do_bindings: couldn't bind an address. Exiting.
>
> [saned] FATAL ERROR; bailing out, waiting for children...
>
> [saned] bail_out: all children exited

Comment: per default webstart applications are run in a very restricted sandbox: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/security.html

Comment: Yes I know that, I set permissions to all-permissions, I got permissions to many things except running system command

Comment: did you set permissions in both the webstart jnlp and the jar manifest?

Comment: sorry can't help you then, didn't do much with webstart myself, and that was the only problem i ran into myself